# Groupwise Maximum with Yii CdbCriteria

Tags: database, yii

I have a table "posts" and a Post can have several comments (foreign-key-relation). I now want to make a join that gives me for each Post the last Comment (with the highest ID).

With "normal SQL" I would use this:

```
SELECT p1.spread, p1.message, p1.id FROM posts AS p1, (SELECT
spread, MAX(id) AS maxid FROM posts GROUP BY spread) AS p2 WHERE
p2.spread = p1.spread AND p1.id = p2.maxid
```

How would I do it with the CDbCriteria or any other method of CActiveRecord? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For the first, your query is quite complicated.. Your result will be the same for the query.

```
SELECT max(id) as id, spread, message 
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY spread
```

Now with the CDbCriteria you have to write your query in related **model**

For example in your case its Posts.php (model)

```
public function last_comment()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'max(id) as id, spread, message';
    $criteria->group = 'spread';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Hope it will help you.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the query you suggested gives me the right id and spread, but not the related message to the id.